# Extension,Selector & add subview via Extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a common functionality of displaying a corner settings list in almost all pages of my application. I have thought of using extension to achieve this common functionality.

**My Code -**

I created a NSObject subclass and within it had an extension of UIViewController -

```
import UIKit

class viewControllerExtension: NSObject
{

}
extension UIViewController
{

    func setCornerSettingsTableView()
    {

       let maskView = UIView()

        maskView.frame = self.view.bounds
        maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        let tableView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cornerSettingVC") as! cornerSettingVC

        addChildViewController(tableView)
        tableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(maskView.frame.width-maskView.frame.width/2.5, 0,self.view.frame.width/2.5, self.view.frame.height-200)
        maskView.addSubview(tableView.view)


        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissMaskView")
        maskView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


        self.view.addSubview(maskView)
    }
      func dismissMaskView()
    {
        print("dismiss called")//function called but how to dismiss the mask View
    }  


}
```

**Usage -**  In any view controller where I need to display i just call -  `setCornerSettingsTableView()`

**Problem -**  As you can see I am trying to add a tap gesture recognizer to my mask view so that whenever user taps the mask view, it removes the mask view along with the table view in it, but I am unable to achieve that.

***If any alternative suggestions for this are most welcome.***

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UIViewController
{

    func setCornerSettingsTableView()
    {
        if let theMask = self.view.viewWithTag(666) as? UIView {
              return  // already setted..
        } else {
           let maskView = UIView()
           maskView.tag = 666
           maskView.frame = self.view.bounds
           maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
           let tableView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cornerSettingVC") as! cornerSettingVC

           addChildViewController(tableView)
           tableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(maskView.frame.width-maskView.frame.width/2.5, 0,self.view.frame.width/2.5, self.view.frame.height-200)
           maskView.addSubview(tableView.view)


           let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissMaskView")
           maskView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


           self.view.addSubview(maskView)
         }
    }

    func dismissMaskView()
    {
        print("dismiss called")//function called but how to dismiss the mask View
        if let theMask = self.view.viewWithTag(666) as? UIView {
            theMask.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }  


}
```

Comment: it is just to locate the view in context :)

Comment: So is this an efficient way to achieve this functionality. Even if we can make the maskView variable accessible to both the functions, then also we can achieve that..

Comment: Yes, the maskView is a subview of your self.view tagged as 666. So, when you can called it with viewWithTag you get one and one only because the first function return if it's already exist.